# Rshiny renderRHandsontable how to update table based on values in one column of table

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable, shinyapps

I am not even sure if my desired output is possible, but wanted to ask in case it is because I am very stuck on this issue.I am building a shiny app where I have an rHandsontableOutput object. When I update the 4th column of the table, I want it to automatically multiply the 5-16 columns of the table by the new values in the 4th column. I'm having difficulty getting my *multiplied* results to display in my table. rHandsontable has been a little tricky for me to grasp. I know how to display the data in a table and then use it in *another* output object, but I am a little confused on how to use it in the same output object. It would preferred to not have to resort to text input to then update the table or some other type of solution that is not in a table format. Any help, or an alternative solution would be much appreciated !

I have referenced a few other posts with no success yet.

[show the sum of specific columns based on rhandsontable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989315/show-the-sum-of-specific-columns-based-on-rhandsontable-values?rq=1)

[Update handsontable by editing table and/or eventReactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722757/update-handsontable-by-editing-table-and-or-eventreactive)

[Flexdashboard, rhandsontable: how to programmatically access user updated table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712551/flexdashboard-rhandsontable-how-to-programmatically-access-user-updated-table)

My code is as follows:

```
#ui

... fluidRow(
              column(width=8,
                     box(
                       width = NULL, div(rHandsontableOutput('contents'), style = "font-size: 92%"),title = "Potential View",
                       status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE)
                     # img(height = "500px", alt="SNAP Logo", src="overlay.png"))

              )


            )...

#server
indat <- reactiveValues(data=table_1)

observe({
  if(!is.null(input$contents))
    indat$data <- hot_to_r(input$contents)

})


output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({

  tbl <- rhandsontable(indat$data) %>% hot_col(col = c(1,2,3), readOnly = TRUE) 

  c=as.vector(tbl$col_4)
  tbl_new = tbl[,c(5:16)]
  test= data.frame(mapply(`*`,tbl_new,c))

  return(test)

})
```

I have also tried updating the table with the hit of a button or creating just one vector that can be edited and binding it with the new table, but I have had no luck with either solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is multiplying the columns, you could try the following:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df <- tibble(
  a = 1:10,
  b = 11:20,
  c = 21:30,
  d = 31:40
)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>        a     b     c     d
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1    11    21    31
#>  2     2    12    22    32
#>  3     3    13    23    33
#>  4     4    14    24    34
#>  5     5    15    25    35
#>  6     6    16    26    36
#>  7     7    17    27    37
#>  8     8    18    28    38
#>  9     9    19    29    39
#> 10    10    20    30    40

df %>% 
  mutate_at(2:4, function(x) x * .$a)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>        a     b     c     d
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1    11    21    31
#>  2     2    24    44    64
#>  3     3    39    69    99
#>  4     4    56    96   136
#>  5     5    75   125   175
#>  6     6    96   156   216
#>  7     7   119   189   259
#>  8     8   144   224   304
#>  9     9   171   261   351
#> 10    10   200   300   400
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You basically use the function `dplyr::mutate_at` to refer to the columns you want to be multiplied. Then, we use the anonymous `function(x)` to multiply column `a` by the columns specified before.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My issue isn't as much multiplying the columns, but, rather, getting the multiplied results to display in my rhandontable table object.